# regex disqualify if followed by a character - How to fix this

Tags: regex

I am using this regex

```
/foo/bar/([^ ]*)/{0,1}(?!.)
```

basically what it should allow

```
/foor/bar/xxxxxx/
                |__optional but nothing after this
```

The string could end in the charact "/" but nothing should be allowed after it.
In order to accomplish this i did

```
 /foo/bar/([^ ]*)/{0,1}(?!.)
            A       B    C
A is ([^ ]*) means allow anything except a space
B is /{0,1} which basically means that the character / should be optional
C is (?!.) which basically is a negative lookahead that no character should be next
```

Am i doing this correct ? If i use the string

```
/foo/bar/somestuff/Whatever
```

if qualifies the regex. I want it to not qualify because of Whatever. What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude `/` in (A):

```
/foo/bar/([^ /]*)/{0,1}(?!.)
```

You can also simplify this further by using `?` instead of `{0,1}` and matching the end of the input (`$`) instead of the negative look-ahead:

```
/foo/bar/([^ /]*)/?$
```

Comment: Could you tell me what ? Is called and what it does ?

Comment: `?` is the question mark.  it means "match 0 or 1" of whatever preceded the `?` - it has exactly the same meaning as `{0,1}` but also works with simpler regular expression parsers that don't understand the `{`m`,`n`}` syntax.